# Idiom for expressing feeling of not willing to talk to a person who always replies in a disrespectful manner?

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

Is there an idiom for expressing the feeling of not willing to talk to a person who always replies in disdain or have such attitude or replies back in a disrespectful manner?

Comment: You can use *stay/keep clear* or *go/get around *.

Comment: Does it need to be an idiom?  I'd just ***avoid*** them.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was "tread lightly."

From Cambridge Dictionaries online "[tread carefully/gently/lightly](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tread-carefully-gently-lightly)":

> to speak or behave carefully to avoid upsetting or causing offence to anyone

The Free Dictionary defines "[tread carefully also tread warily](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tread+carefully)" as follows:

> to avoid saying or doing anything that could cause difficulties

It gives the following usage note, which comes close to fitting your purposes:

> sometimes used in the form tread cautiously: You should tread cautiously when discussing financial matters with him.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any idiom for wanting to avoid talking to someone with the characteristics you describe, but if it helps, you might describe the person as [**abrasive**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abrasive)

> Showing little concern for the feelings of others; harsh

or perhaps [**caustic**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/caustic)

> Sarcastic or scathing in a bitter way

In a sentence: "I won't talk to John these days, he's become unbearably abrasive."

Answer (score 0):

I try to ***avoid them like the plague***.  This idiom is defined by [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/avoid+like+the+plague)

> avoid someone or something like the plague
>
> Fig. to ignore or keep away from someone or something totally. What's
>   wrong with Bob? Everyone avoids him like the plague. I don't like
>   opera. I avoid it like the plague......
>
> This seemingly modern expression dates from the Latin of the early
>   Middle Ages, when Saint Jerome (a.d. 345-420) wrote, "Avoid, as you
>   would the plague, a clergyman who is also a man of business." The
>   plague, a deadly infectious disease in his day, has been largely wiped
>   out, but the term remains current.

Answer (score 0):

Although they are not specific to the issues you describe, by mentioning the particular problems at issue, you could perhaps use one or more of the following idiomatic verb phrases to express your feelings:

1- "[to] [do without something"](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/do-without) phrasal verb:

**can/could do without something**   spoken
 used for saying that something is annoying you and causing problems for you:
“I could do without all these interruptions.” ;

2- “[to] [have no need of something](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/have-no-need-of-something)”  phrase
to not need something
“We have no need of this old software now that we have a new system.”
    To not want something, or to not want to do something;   or

3- “[to] [have no use for something](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/have-no-use-for#have-no-use-for__1)”  phrase
1 used for saying that you do not want or need someone or something because they could never be helpful to you
“The new owners may decide they have no use for the present management.”
To not want something, or to not want to do something:
2  informal to dislike someone or something
“I have no use for a liar.”
To hate or dislike someone or something:

(all from *MacMillan Dictionary*)

[“I can do without(/I have no need of/use for) [him and] his attitude [his disdainful/disrespectful replies].”](https://books.google.com/books?id=lupU30hmDewC&pg=PA83&dq=%22i+can+do+without+his%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyqPDE85XNAhXErD4KHfyOD_wQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22i%20can%20do%20without%20his%22&f=false)
(example usage of “can do without” from *The Grin of the Dark* by Ramsey Campbell, via ‘Google Books’)

Of the three suggestions mentioned above, I’d say that “**to have no** [further] **use for**” (especially with “further” added) would express best the finality of your decision to stop talking to this individual, but if s/he still doesn’t get the message (and if you don’t mind being a little disrespectful yourself) you could interrupt their next utterance with the old [“Talk to the hand”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk_to_the_hand) routine followed quickly by the bridge-burning *coup de grâce* [“You’re dead to me.”](https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-when-someone-says-Youre-dead-to-me)
(from *Wikipedia* and *Quora*, respectively)